Artifacts during playback of RTSP using FFmpeg API
I need to play RTSP video from an IP camera.
If I use ffplay or VLC, everything is fine.
But if I use FFmpeg API (C#, FFmpeg.AutoGen), then artifacts appear on the frames. What could be wrong with using FFmpeg API?
UPDATE
On Christoph's advice, I tried replacing UDP with TCP for ffplay.

Both TCP and UDP give a delay of 3-4 seconds (my application gives a delay of less than one second).

Both TCP and UDP work without artifacts.

When UDP is used, there are error messages at the beginning:


max delay reached. need to consume packet
RTP: missed 436 packets
Invalid level prefix
error while decoding MB 17 28

These errors are only at the beginning. Then there are no errors.
When TCP is used, no errors are reported at all.

The discardcorrupt flag in my application does not fix artifacts.

If I use TCP in my application (rtsp_transport=tcp flag), the artifacts disappear. This is good. But I wouldn't want to create an extra load on the network because of TCP. In addition, there may be a video delay.


How do ffplay and VLC work on UDP without artifacts? Why can't API do this?

AVFormatContext* pFormatContext = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();

int error;

error = ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, rtspUrl, null, null);

if (error != 0)
    throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

error = ffmpeg.avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext, null);

if (error != 0)
    throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

AVStream* pStream = null;

for (var i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
{
    if (pFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        pStream = pFormatContext->streams[i];
    }
}

if (pStream == null)
    throw new ApplicationException(@"Could not found video stream.");

AVCodecContext codecContext = *pStream->codec;

int width = codecContext.width;
int height = codecContext.height;
AVPixelFormat sourcePixFmt = codecContext.pix_fmt;
AVCodecID codecId = codecContext.codec_id;

AVPixelFormat destinationPixFmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;

if (sourcePixFmt == AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_NONE && codecId == AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
{
    sourcePixFmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
}

SwsContext* pConvertContext = ffmpeg.sws_getContext(width, height, sourcePixFmt, width, height, destinationPixFmt, ffmpeg.SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, null, null, null);

if (pConvertContext == null)
    throw new ApplicationException(@"Could not initialize the conversion context.");

AVFrame* pConvertedFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();

int convertedFrameBufferSize = ffmpeg.av_image_get_buffer_size(destinationPixFmt, width, height, 1);

IntPtr convertedFrameBufferPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(convertedFrameBufferSize);

byte_ptrArray4 dstData = new byte_ptrArray4();
int_array4 dstLinesize = new int_array4();

ffmpeg.av_image_fill_arrays(ref dstData, ref dstLinesize, (byte*)convertedFrameBufferPtr, destinationPixFmt, width, height, 1);



WorkEnabled = true;

AVCodec* pCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_decoder(codecId);

if (pCodec == null)
    throw new ApplicationException(@"Unsupported codec.");

AVCodecContext* pCodecContext = &codecContext;

if ((pCodec->capabilities & ffmpeg.AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED) == ffmpeg.AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
{
    pCodecContext->flags |= ffmpeg.AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;
}

error = ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, null);

if (error < 0)
    throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

AVFrame* pDecodedFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();

AVPacket packet = new AVPacket();
AVPacket* pPacket = &packet;
ffmpeg.av_init_packet(pPacket);


Bitmap bitmap = null;
Bitmap previousbBitmap = null;

while (WorkEnabled)
{
    try
    {
        do
        {
            error = ffmpeg.av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket);

            if (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
            if (error < 0)
                throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

            if (pPacket->stream_index != pStream->index) continue;

            error = ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);

            if (error < 0)
                throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

            error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pDecodedFrame);


        } while (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN) && WorkEnabled);

        if (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }
        if (error < 0)
            throw new ApplicationException(Helpers.GetErrorMessage(error));

        if (pPacket->stream_index != pStream->index) continue;

        // YUV->RGB
        ffmpeg.sws_scale(pConvertContext, pDecodedFrame->data, pDecodedFrame->linesize, 0, height, dstData, dstLinesize);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}
    finally
    {
        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
    }

    bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, dstLinesize[0], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, convertedFrameBufferPtr);

    previousbBitmap = bitmap;

    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _pictureBox.Image = bitmap);

}


Is it Always? These h264 artifacts normally happen when there is a tcp or udp packet loss. You should activate or integrate the ffmpeg logging there you would see whats going on. Try to reduce FPS,Bitrate or Resolution to check if its releated to Network

@Christoph It's not permanent. Let's say it happens because of packet loss. But ffplay and VLC somehow cope with it.

You could try Force using tcp as rtsp/rtp transport, also you can try using discard corrupted flag.

@Christoph Added to the post the result of changing UDP to TCP.

You have package loss so fix your Network, you could try to Figure Out correct flags. Ffmpeg sometimes complicated what are the correct ones. If you discard or drop corrupted of course you would have frame drop. codec_ctx->err_recognition |= AV_EF_EXPLODE;  // Discard corrupted frames     codec_ctx->flags2 |= AV_CODEC_FLAG2_DROP_FRAME_TIMECODE;  // Drop corrupted frames

@Christoph Your hint about the TCP helped me find the solution. Thanks for your help!

Similar problem was discussed here and here. It turned out that for UDP it is necessary to increase the buffer size.
ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&formatOpts, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 0);
ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&formatOpts, "buffer_size", "200000", 0);
ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, url, null, &formatOpts);

And the artifacts disappeared!
